# Updating entity framework model after changing the data type of column in database table

Tags: entity-framework-6, mapping, member, sqldatatypes, updatemodel

I am working with entity framework 6 with database 1st approach. I changed the datatype of my columns in the table and after updating my model I got the following  error:

> Error 1   Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type
>   'Edm.Int32[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'Warranty' in type
>   'pjModel.Bill' is not compatible with
>   'SqlServer.nvarchar[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=50,Unicode=True,FixedLength=False]'
>   of member 'Warranty' in type 'pjModel.Store.Bills'.

what I understand that there is some compatibility issue between datatypes of framework and sql server.
Also when I opened the .edmx file with XML viewer, it clearly shows that changes are propagated in the model i.e data type has been updated, but in the diagram view when I right click the particular column it still shows the old datatype.

I can provide more information if required.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. I manually change the type from the diagram view and then it get mapped with the model class.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, using EF6, after changing on a database table a field from int to bit.

It was not enought to delete property from model designer, and create it again, as the table mapping refered to the old type.

[image]

I guess this could be useful for similar cases. The only way to solve it (unless you don't mind deleting entity and updating model from database) is to **edit your Entity Data Model as text** (by default,  `DataModel.edmx`), locate the entity as `<Entity>` node inside `<Schema>` node and find the desired property that indicates the old type. As an example:

```
<Property Name="MyProperty" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
```

Simply change `Type` attribute to the desired type, return to Visual Studio, save the `edmx` file, and rebuild.